Adding multiple event listeners for same event in socket io/react
I have a global context which listens to a new-message event.
SocketContext.js (global)
 useEffect(() => {
         if (!socket) return

         socket.on("new_message", (data) => {
            // Dont run the code if we're on /chat (as that means there is another listener with same name attatched)
            if (pathname === "/chat") return              

            // Update chats latest message. This should only run if we aren't on /chat route
            dispatch(updateChat({ data: data.message}))
        })

        return () => socket.off("new_message")
}, [socket])

I have a Chat component where the local messages state should be updated when a new message is received
Chat.js (rendered when user visits /chat route)
const [messages, setMessages) = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  if (!socket) return

  socket.on("new_message", (data) => {
      setMessages((prev) => [...prev, data.message])
  })

  return () => socket.off("new_message")
}, [socket])

Both components listen to the same event. But both do different things depending on whether the user is on the /chat route. The code inside the global event listener wont run if the route is /chat but the event is still fired and being listened to globally (even when we're listening to the same event when on the /chat route).
Is this considered bad practise (adding two event listeners with the same name in different places)? One alternative is to add one event listener globally, however then I would have to store messages state globally in order to update it.

There is nothing wrong with your approach if it suits you well.
However, having a global state which represents single source of truth will save you from potential bugs and issues.
It is better to create several things:

Create a context:

import { createContext } from 'react';

interface MessagesContextType { messages: Message[]; }

export const MessagesContext = createContext<MessagesContextType>({ messages: [] });


create a context provider:

import React, { PropsWithChildren, useEffect } from 'react';

interface Props {
   socket: Socket;
}

export const MessagesContextProvider: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({ socket, children }) => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!socket) return;
        socket.on('new_message', (data) => {
            setMessages((prev) => [...prev, data.message]);
        });
        return () => socket.off('new_message');
    }, [socket]);
    
    const value: MessagesContextType = { messages}

    return <MessagesContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</MessagesContext.Provider>;
};



create a hook:

export const useMessagesContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(MessagesContext);
    if (!context) throw new Error('No MessagesContext provider is found');
    return context;
};


Wrap somewhere globally your jsx tree with MessagesContextProvider:

<MessagesContextProvider socket={socket}>
  <YourApp/>
<MessagesContextProvider/>


use hook where you need to read your messages (eg. Chat component):

const messages = useMessages();

Also, be aware, that in your code snippets you defined deps [socket] for the useEffect, but you forgot add pathname to deps. It means, that if pathname changes, pathname in your event listener won't change! This is because of what is called "closures" in javascript (however, closures is just a naive explanation of what ecmascript does. You can read about it in https://tc39.es/ecma262/
